# How do I make the shadow blend smoothly with the background?

Tags: python, image-processing

[image: An example]

I'm trying to blend the shadow at the bottom right of the person smoothly with the background. What kind of image processing filter should I use?

I'm trying to do this in Python using Scipy library not Photoshop.

Comment: What do you mean by "blend smoothly" with the background?   Do you want the bottom right of the person to exhibit the same colour as the rest of the background?

Comment: Yes, basically, makes the shadow colour transition smoothly with the background colour.

Comment: Perhaps segment out the person so that all you have left is the background, then replace all of the background pixels with the mean?  What can and can't you do to get the job done?

Comment: How do you segment out the person? I can do it only in Python, as I want to do the same thing with thousands of other images.

Comment: Doing that automatically will be exceedingly difficult, especially since the distribution of intensities for the shadows will change.  In Python, what are you allowed to use?  I would recommend `scikit-image` instead of `scipy` for this.  http://scikit-image.org/ - It's much more powerful when dealing with image processing related tasks.  Perhaps take a look at random walks and instead of extracting out the person, determine which pixels belong to the background, then replace all those pixels with one colour: http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_random_walker_segmentation.html